# How to configure php 7.4 opcache to register cache hits?

Tags: php, opcache

PHP containers are running with the command php-fpm.
When I exec into one of them and run.

```
$ php -a
php > print_r(opcache_get_status());
```

I get the following results

```
(
    [opcache_enabled] => 1
    [cache_full] =>
    [restart_pending] =>
    [restart_in_progress] =>
    [memory_usage] => Array
        (
            [used_memory] => 20976088
            [free_memory] => 180350504
            [wasted_memory] => 0
            [current_wasted_percentage] => 0
        )

    [interned_strings_usage] => Array
        (
            [buffer_size] => 6291008
            [used_memory] => 499216
            [free_memory] => 5791792
            [number_of_strings] => 10395
        )

    [opcache_statistics] => Array
        (
            [num_cached_scripts] => 0
            [num_cached_keys] => 0
            [max_cached_keys] => 262237
            [hits] => 0
            [start_time] => 1658153738
            [last_restart_time] => 0
            [oom_restarts] => 0
            [hash_restarts] => 0
            [manual_restarts] => 0
            [misses] => 0
            [blacklist_misses] => 0
            [blacklist_miss_ratio] => 0
            [opcache_hit_rate] => 0
        )

    [scripts] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Why are the hits 0?
Am I looking in the wrong place?
Is my configuration wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at the CLI's status, you need to look at the web process's which is either the CGI or FPM one. There's also a [dedicated setting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.enable-cli) for CLI OP Cache that you could enable, but it probably doesn't make sense which is why it is disabled by default.

So to see this, make a page that you execute with an HTTP request that calls [`phpinfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)